# Is there any ways to use maps in application without registering API key?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any ways to use maps in application without registering API key.

Comment: nope! I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to use the API key to access the Map service.  You cannot use the service without registering and using a key.

They use the API key to limit calls to the service, or other things that might cause an issue with their service infrastructure (otherwise, anyone could make as many calls as they want without limit or issue).

More info: [Maps API Info](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)